# Midpoint Algorithm in drawing line c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, algorithm, visual-c++, graphics

This midpoint algorithm in c++ win32 doesn't work. It draws nothing or only horizontal lines. What error(s) am I making?

```
void midPoint(HDC hdc)
{

    double dx = end.getXPoint()-start.getXPoint();
    double dy = end.getYPoint()-start.getYPoint();

    double x = start.getXPoint();
    double y = start.getYPoint();
    SetPixel(hdc,x,y,color);

    double d = dx - (dy/2);
    double d1 = dx;
    double d2 = abs(dx-dy);

    while(x < end.getXPoint())
    {
    d = abs(((( y+0.5)-start.getYPoint())*dx) - (((x+1)-start.getXPoint())*dy));

    if(d < 0)
    {
        x = x+1;
        y = y+1;
    }
    else
    {
        x = x+1;
    }
    SetPixel(hdc,x,y,color);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4):

Your d is never <0. Revise the formula for d, especially the ( and ).

```
d = abs(((( y+0.5)-start.getYPoint())*dx) - (((x+1)-start.getXPoint())*dy));

    if(d < 0)
    {
        x = x+1;
        y = y+1;   // never executed
    }
    else
    {
        x = x+1;   // horizontal line
    }
    SetPixel(hdc,x,y,color);
```

Comment: Yes, this is only the first error. Could you post a link to the algorithm?

Comment: You calcule d1 and d2 but never use it.  ??

Comment: you can take a look at this [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham's_line_algorithm)

Comment: because the formula do same thing

Comment: Your coordenat are double or int?

Comment: If int, do they map directly to pixels?

Comment: they are int but I used double for division

Comment: Ok. Please test if (d<0.5)  where you have if(d<0). It will work only for dx and dy >0

Comment: I did also draw horizontal lines

Comment: And simple withow the abs and with d<0?

Answer (score 1):

As you are taking the abs value in the calculation of d, it will never be less than 0. So the value of X is alone getting incremented and you are getting the horizontal line.